# Unable to download checksum files (SHA256SUMS), they just open a text window on firefox. How do I actually download the files?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, checksums, sha256

I'm trying to verify the iso file I've downloaded, but I can't download the checksum files from http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/. When I press the links they open as another tab on firefox.

Comment: Sorry I use `wget` to download them (from a terminal), but I'd expect right-clicking would allow a "save" option (instead of left-clicking the links).

Comment: If you open the link (sha1sum, md5sum), right click has a SAVE AS option which saves it as a text file (ie. download equivalent).  *Firefox 67.0.4*

Comment: Thank you, I've downloaded the checksum files now. However, do you know where they are put in windows? The tutorial for verifying the iso file says they need to be in the same place as the iso

Comment: It is my belief that your browser settings dictate where they get stored.  My browser always asks me where I want to save files, as I have told the browser to ask me (it defaults always to the last place I saved files). You can however control where it saves them - so check your browser settings.

Comment: @guiverc I've used the wget command so the files are in the same place as the terminal, however when I use the command:                                         sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2<&1 | grep OK                                                there is no output. This is despite me placing the .iso file in the same directory and having downloaded it from the Ubuntu website. Do you have any ideas why?